# FireMonkey Getting FMXObjects at runtime using RTTI

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm trying to get (using `RTTI`), the `forms` that are in my app, in order to create them at `runtime`, based on the forms `Name`.

I've declared the `{$TYPEINFO ON}` compiler directive and I coded:

```
 lRttiType := pRttiContext.FindType ('Forms.tForm');
```

but I get a `nil` result.

`'Forms.tForm'` should be the forms `Name`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Querying_for_Type_Information#Getting_Information_for_a_Specific_Type) says:

> `TRttiContext.FindType`, which looks up the type information based on the qualified type name. The qualified type name is made up of two components: unit name, separated by the dot character from the type name (for example, `Classes.TStrings`).

The full `QualifiedName` for the `TForm` of the Firemonkey framework will be: `FMX.Forms.TForm`

Note that the `QualifiedName` is case-sensitive.

```
lRttiType := pRttiContext.FindType ('FMX.Forms.TForm'); // this finds the TRttiType
lRttiType := pRttiContext.FindType ('fmx.forms.TForm'); // this will return nil
```

Also note that, `FMX.Forms.TForm` is a `TPersistent` descendant, which is compiled with the `{$M+`} directive, which is an alias of `{$TYPEINFO ON}`. So, you won't need to enable it to access `TForm` RTTI

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now, as I stated earlier, how can I find the `FMX` `form`, based on its name?

Comment: You just use the Qualified Name. The Qualified Name belongs to a class. If your class is declared in MyUnit as TMyForm = class(TForm) then the Qualified Name will be MyUnit.TMyForm

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It happens that `RTTI` can't help me to achieve my goal, wich is to retrieve the `forms` using its `names`. That is because (as my test corrobarates), the `forms` must been have created first, in order to `RTTI` can find any information about them. So I simply set them to be created automatically, in the `Options->Forms` settings.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. What are you actually trying to achieve? RTTI stands for runtime type information. That is, it gives you information about a given type. Not about an object instance.

Comment: @ppro - to have RTTI available, a class needs to be referenced somewhere, otherwise the smart linker will remove it and any associated RTTI. One way to reference a class is to instantiate it, but that's not the only way - just adding TMyForm.ClassName in a unit's initialization section will do.